# Display form content on same template django

Tags: django, forms, django-views

So I am working on django, I have a simple form with one text field named "sujet", here's the form.py code:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    sujet = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'id': 'id_sujet', 
                'style': 'border-color: blue;',
                'placeholder': 'Write your name here'
            }
        )
        )
```

The template "contact.html" where the user can fill the form is the following:

```
<form id="myForm" action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post">
    {{ form.sujet }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="response">
    Sujet : <span id="sujeet"></span>
    {{ sujet }}
</div>
```

In my "views.py" I want my contact function to render the variable "sujet" to the template so I can diplay it on "contact.html" after filling and submitting the form (the intended usage of this is later to display the result of the database query that concerns sujet and not the variable itself but I am still working on that), here's the code of the view function :

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        sujet = form.cleaned_data['sujet']
        envoi = True
        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'], {'sujet':sujet})
    else:
        return render(request, 'voirkpi/contact.html', locals())
```

Here is the code of my "urls.py" :

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accueil', views.ligneerabstat),
    path('spark', views.kpitest),
    path('testchart', views.testchart),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    #path('test', views.test, name='test'),
    url('test', views.test, name='test')
]
```

My problem is that after clicking submit sujet is empty and doesn't show anything, I did make this work with simple javascript, but that's not what I want as the intended usage of this is as I said later to query a database and return in that span the result of the query according to the "sujet" filled. 
Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In the case where it is valid, you are doing a `redirect`... Did you mean to do a `render` instead? Also the second argument is `permanent` but it looks like you're passing context

Comment: In case it is valid, what I want to do is send "sujet" to the same template, that's why I am redirecting it to the same template the form was submitted from, if there is another way to do it, please suggest it to me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. You're right Resley Rodrigues, I solved my problem by changing my contact function in "views.py" like so:

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        sujet = form.cleaned_data['sujet']
        envoi = True
        form = ContactForm()
        return render(request,'voirkpi/contact.html',locals(), {'sujet' : sujet})
    else:
        return render(request, 'voirkpi/contact.html', locals())
```